# Hide menu item "warehouse" in openerp6.1

Tags: odoo

In **openerp6.1** I am working on warehouse(stock) 
I am trying to customize  stock and create new warehouse_management module now I want to hide original **warehouse** menu,sub menu and put my own **WMS** menu internally I use many functionality of stock, so if I delete menu item i can't access existing functionality 
  I just want to hide warehouse menu and its sub menu
Requirement is when I am install my wms module it automatically hide warehouse menu

Answer (score 0):

if you not want to delete menu then you can done one thing, create a new group and overwrite the same menu again in your module

```
<menuitem name="Project" id="base.menu_main_pm" groups="group_new_hide" sequence="40"/>
```

So until you give this new group any user the menu remain hidden

Hope this help